# Discord.py: How do I add an image in my discord bot's rich presence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I was working on a bot recently and I got to know that I can add images in Bot's Rich presence too. So I created another Bot to test it. I read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=activity#discord.Activity) for it and gave it a try but didn't get any result.

The code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

ndcr = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=discord.Intents.all(), case_insensitive=True)

@ndcr.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ONLINE NOW ;)")
    botactivity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="for crimes in New Delhi and conducting hearings for them.", large_image_url='https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/290-2907032_court-quest-court-clipart-hd-png-download.png')
    await ndcr.change_presence(activity=botactivity, status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb)


ndcr.run('Hidden Bruh. Why do you wanna see it? :/')
```

So what I want is that is show me the image I want it to. [This](https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/290-2907032_court-quest-court-clipart-hd-png-download.png) is the image I want to add in the presence.

This is how the presence look even after this code:

[image: Current Presence]

Note: I have tried adding this link in `small_image_text` and `large_image_text` already. Once each time. Yet no luck.

---

Please let me know if there is anything I am doing wrong and if possible give me some example with respect to my code.

Thank You! :D

Comment: These are called rich presences, Unfortunately bots accounts cannot have presences with clickable buttons or images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add images to your bot's activity. It is possible to customize Rich Presence shown on your account through programs like EasyRP.

You can check it here: https://github.com/Pizzabelly/EasyRP